# Symfony form_errors(form) wrong field name, bug or my code is wrong?

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, symfony-forms

I've a problem displaying form errors with `{% form_errors(form) %}`. **Message displayed is wrong, fields are inverted**. Don't know if this is a bug or my bad.

Anyway, this is part of my controller action, where i'm creating a new form type not bound to any object or entity:

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        // NOTE not passing any data to createForm method
        $context = $this->get('security.context');
        $form    = $this->createForm(new SendMailType($context));

        if('GET' == $request->getMethod()) // GET
            return array('form' => $form->createView());

        $form->bindRequest($request); // POST

        if(!$form->isValid()) return array('form' => $form->createView());

        return new Response('Form is valid');
    }
}
```

Where `SendMailType` has two fields, `recipient` and `text`. `recipient` can't be blank.

```
class SendMailType extends AbstractType
{

    /**
     * @var Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext
     */
    protected $context;

    public function __construct(SecurityContext $context)
    {
        $this->context = $context;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('recipient', 'text')
            ->add('text', 'textarea');
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'validation_constraint' => new Collection(array(
                'recipient' => array(new NotBlank()),
            ))
        );
    }

    public function getName() { return 'send_mail'; }
}
```

On **POST** using `{% form_errors(form) %}` i'm getting the error:

> Fields "text" are invalid.

As you can see **this is completely wrong**, because the field `text` has no validation rules specified. On the other hand, the `recipient` field itself shows the correct error:

> This value should not be blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of surprised that it worked at all.  In any event this will solve the problem:

```
public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
{
    return array(
        'validation_constraint' => new Collection(array(
            'allowExtraFields' => true,
            'fields' => array('recipient' => array(new NotBlank())),
        ))
    );
}
```

Comment: How can `allowExtraFields` option explain the weird message about field `text`?

Comment: By default the system assumes that all fields will be validated.  So the complaint is that 'text' has no validation and thus must be invalid.  Bit strange but there you go.